# error using JAXB xjc generated classes from qbxml xsd schema

Tags: xml, jaxb, xsd, qbxml

i'm trying to generate classes that i can use from the validator xsd files found in:

`C:\Program Files\Intuit\IDN\Common\tools\validator`

i run:

`xjc qbxmltypes.xsd qbxml.xsd qbxmlso.xsd qbxmlops.xsd`

and the tool generates the 'generated' directory and class files as expected.  however, these classes don't appear to work properly.  i add the classes to my project, repackage them, and everything compiles just fine.  when i create a new JAXBContext object thus:

`JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(ObjectFactory.class);`

in the normal way, this compiles just fine, but i get runtime errors (lots of them, repeating the same line) in System.err that read:

`No XmlSchema annotation found for [packagenamehere]`

i search the package path for usages of the XmlSchema, and none are found.  JAXB apparently requires this at runtime.

am i using the wrong .xsd files?  should i be adding the XmlSchema annotation to the ObjectFactory.java class?  what am i doing wrong here?  i think i'm just building the wrong classes with xjc.  which .xsd files should i be compiling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The XJC utility will generate classes into a package name based on the target namespace.  If there isn't one the by default it will put them in a package called generated.  You can supply a package name as a parameter.

```
xjc -p com.example.foo schema.xsd
```

I would recommend generating each of your schemas into a separate package.  When creating a `JAXBContext` from classes generated from an XML schema I always recommend doing this on the package name.  When there are multiple package names simply separate them with the `.` character.

```
JAXBContect jc = JAXBContext.newInstance("com.example.foo:com.example.bar");
```

Comment: this has nothing to do with the issue at hand lol.  and you didn't read the question thoroughly.

Comment: @moonlightcheese - I reread your question and I believe everything I said still applies.  Specifying the `-p` flag eliminates the need to repackage your classes.  And creating a `JAXBContext` on the package name and not the `ObjectFactory` wiil work better for you.

Comment: thanks for the reply.  i did try exactly what you posted here, to the letter.  rebuilt the classes from schema and used `JAXBContext.newInstance("com.example.qbxml.jaxb")` which is the package in which the JAXB classes reside.  the same problem persists.  i glanced through this: [XmlSchema](http://jaxb.java.net/nonav/2.2.4/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSchema.html) and it seems like JAXB wants this annotation defined in a file called package-info.java.

Comment: @moonlightcheese - Yes the `@XmlSchema` annotations is a package level annotation on goes in a class for which the source files name is `package-info.java` (see:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/08/jaxb-namespaces.html).  Your JAXB impl should generate this for you (if its needed).  I can't think of a use case where you need to add one manually after the fact.

Comment: hmmm... actually, it may be related to [the repackaged library](http://www.docx4java.org/blog/2012/05/jaxb-can-be-made-to-run-on-android/) i'm using.  toward the bottom, where he mentions that annotations failed to read on Android, he links [Context.java](https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/blob/android/src/main/java/org/docx4j/jaxb/Context.java) in which he tells Android about the namespaces.  also, package-info.java was not automatically generated from the .xsd files, but does this matter?

Comment: @moonlightcheese - You could always try it out in a standard Java SE install to make everything work to confirm that the problem is with the Android port.

Comment: i'm just going to go with Simple XML, as it's widely used in Android apps.  this guy's port of JAXB just seems hacky, and it's causing more frustration than anything.  JAXB isn't meant to run on Android anyway, and may cause memory and apk size problems.  i was trying to use it to get around translating 543 schema classes created with xjc from JAXB to Simple annotations.  no way around it, it seems.  it's too bad there's no tool for generating Simple XML classes from .xsd schema files.  thanks for all of your help.